# SQLs with Grouping Set do not return the same result

Tags: oracle11g, grouping-sets

I have 2 queries with Grouping set. Before doing grouping set, I have checked the result are totally the same. The values of L_TIM_53_ID and L_TIM_54_ID are always 2458120. But I got a different result with the following 2 Queries.

Query A,

```
SELECT NVL(TABLE_A.PRD_LVL_MEMBER_ID,2147483647) AS L_PRD_1_ID
,NVL(TABLE_A.TIM_52_ID,2147483647) AS L_TIM_52_ID
,NVL(TABLE_A.TIM_53_ID,2147483647) AS L_TIM_53_ID
,NVL(TABLE_A.TIM_54_ID,2147483647) AS L_TIM_54_ID
,sum(ADJ_BOOK_HISTORY) AS M_ADJ_BOOK_HISTORY
FROM (SELECT TIM_LEVEL_ID,TIM_LVL_MEMBER_ID,TIM_51_ID,TIM_54_ID,TIM_53_ID,TIM_52_ID,DCS_LVL_MEMBER_ID,PRD_LVL_MEMBER_ID,CUS_LVL_MEMBER_ID,ORG_LVL_MEMBER_ID FROM TABLE_A,(SELECT TIM_LEVEL_ID,TIM_LVL_MEMBER_ID,TIM_51_ID,TIM_54_ID,TIM_53_ID,TIM_52_ID
FROM MSC_DIMENSION_TIM_DYD
WHERE ((MSC_DIMENSION_TIM_DYD.TIM_53_ID IN (2458120)) AND (MSC_DIMENSION_TIM_DYD.TIM_54_ID IN (2458120)))
AND TIM_LEVEL_ID = 51
AND AGGR_TIM_LEVEL_ID = 51
GROUP BY TIM_LEVEL_ID,TIM_LVL_MEMBER_ID,TIM_51_ID,TIM_54_ID,TIM_53_ID,TIM_52_ID) MISSING_DATES) TABLE_A
,TABLE_B
WHERE TABLE_A.TIM_LVL_MEMBER_ID = TABLE_B.TIM_LVL_MEMBER_ID(+)
AND TABLE_A.DCS_LVL_MEMBER_ID = TABLE_B.DCS_LVL_MEMBER_ID(+)
AND TABLE_A.PRD_LVL_MEMBER_ID = TABLE_B.PRD_LVL_MEMBER_ID(+)
AND TABLE_A.CUS_LVL_MEMBER_ID = TABLE_B.CUS_LVL_MEMBER_ID(+)
AND TABLE_A.ORG_LVL_MEMBER_ID = TABLE_B.ORG_LVL_MEMBER_ID(+)
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
(TABLE_A.TIM_54_ID)
,(TABLE_A.PRD_LVL_MEMBER_ID,TABLE_A.TIM_52_ID,TABLE_A.TIM_53_ID,TABLE_A.TIM_54_ID)
)
```

Query B,

```
SELECT NVL(TABLE_A.PRD_LVL_MEMBER_ID,2147483647) AS L_PRD_1_ID
,NVL(TABLE_A.TIM_52_ID,2147483647) AS L_TIM_52_ID
,NVL(TABLE_A.TIM_53_ID,2147483647) AS L_TIM_53_ID
,NVL(TABLE_A.TIM_54_ID,2147483647) AS L_TIM_54_ID
,sum(ADJ_BOOK_HISTORY) AS M_ADJ_BOOK_HISTORY
FROM (SELECT TIM_LEVEL_ID,TIM_LVL_MEMBER_ID,TIM_51_ID,TIM_54_ID,TIM_53_ID,TIM_52_ID,DCS_LVL_MEMBER_ID,PRD_LVL_MEMBER_ID,CUS_LVL_MEMBER_ID,ORG_LVL_MEMBER_ID FROM TABLE_A,(SELECT TIM_LEVEL_ID,TIM_LVL_MEMBER_ID,TIM_51_ID,TIM_54_ID,TIM_53_ID,TIM_52_ID
FROM MSC_DIMENSION_TIM_DYD
WHERE ((MSC_DIMENSION_TIM_DYD.TIM_53_ID IN (2458120)))
AND TIM_LEVEL_ID = 51
AND AGGR_TIM_LEVEL_ID = 51
GROUP BY TIM_LEVEL_ID,TIM_LVL_MEMBER_ID,TIM_51_ID,TIM_54_ID,TIM_53_ID,TIM_52_ID) MISSING_DATES) TABLE_A
,TABLE_B
WHERE TABLE_A.TIM_LVL_MEMBER_ID = TABLE_B.TIM_LVL_MEMBER_ID(+)
AND TABLE_A.DCS_LVL_MEMBER_ID = TABLE_B.DCS_LVL_MEMBER_ID(+)
AND TABLE_A.PRD_LVL_MEMBER_ID = TABLE_B.PRD_LVL_MEMBER_ID(+)
AND TABLE_A.CUS_LVL_MEMBER_ID = TABLE_B.CUS_LVL_MEMBER_ID(+)
AND TABLE_A.ORG_LVL_MEMBER_ID = TABLE_B.ORG_LVL_MEMBER_ID(+)
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
(TABLE_A.TIM_54_ID)
,(TABLE_A.PRD_LVL_MEMBER_ID,TABLE_A.TIM_52_ID,TABLE_A.TIM_53_ID,TABLE_A.TIM_54_ID)
)
```

Result for Query A,

```
12143       2458120     2458120     2458120     25.4794520578945205476403721461486967
12143       2458151     2458120     2458120     23.0136986329369863010945296803923712
12143       2458179     2458120     2458120     25.4794520578945205476403721461486967
2147483647  2147483647  2147483647  2147483647  73.9726027487260273963752739726897647
```

Result for Query B,

```
12143       2458120     2458120     2458120 25.47945205789452054764037214614869673869
12143       2458151     2458120     2458120 23.01369863293698630109452968039237124785
12143       2458179     2458120     2458120 25.47945205789452054764037214614869673869
2147483647  2147483647  2147483647  2458120 73.97260274872602739637527397268976472523
```

We can clearly see the issued group set is for **TABLE_A.TIM_54_ID**, I don't know what is the difference between these 2 SQL. Why they return the different results?